# conda PackagesNotFoundError for packages installed from "free" channel

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to install `fastspar` into an existing conda environment, but I get the following `ResolvePackageNotFound` error:

```
conda install -c bioconda fastspar
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - defaults/linux-64::natsort==3.5.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pyparsing==2.0.3=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::qt==4.8.7=3
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl==11.3.3=0
  - defaults/linux-64::mysql-python==1.2.5=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::freetype==2.5.5=1
  - defaults/linux-64::fontconfig==2.11.1=6
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy==1.10.4=py27_2
  - defaults/linux-64::cairo==1.12.18=6
  - defaults/linux-64::py2cairo==1.10.0=py27_2
  - defaults/linux-64::libgfortran==3.0.0=1
  - defaults/linux-64::libgcc-ng==7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
  - defaults/linux-64::scipy==0.17.1=np110py27_1
  - defaults/linux-64::libpng==1.6.17=0
  - defaults/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng==7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
  - defaults/linux-64::matplotlib==1.4.3=np110py27_2
```

However, these packages were indeed already installed, as results from `conda list`, but are flagged as installed from the obsolete conda channel `free`.

```
conda list |grep free

cairo                     1.12.18                       6    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
fontconfig                2.11.1                        6    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
freetype                  2.5.5                         1    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
gdata                     2.0.18                   py27_0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
libpng                    1.6.17                        0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
matplotlib                1.4.3               np110py27_2    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
mkl                       11.3.3                        0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
mysql-python              1.2.5                    py27_0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
natsort                   3.5.0                    py27_0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
numpy                     1.10.4                   py27_2    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
py2cairo                  1.10.0                   py27_2    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py27_0    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
qt                        4.8.7                         3    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
scipy                     0.17.1              np110py27_1    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
```

Following the suggestion by @merv, I added `free` to my channel list

```
> conda config --add channels free
> conda config --set restore_free_channel true
> conda config --set channel_priority flexible
    
> conda config --show channels
    channels:
      - conda-forge
      - bioconda
      - defaults
      - free
      - biobakery
```

This made the trick to get rid of missing packages in `free` channel. However, a couple of new `ResolvePackageNotFound` error raised

```
conda install -c bioconda fastspar

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
- defaults/linux-64::libgcc-ng==7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
- defaults/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng==7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
```

This two packages are indeed present in my environment, but with no channel indication:

```
> conda list|grep "libgcc-ng\|libstdcxx-ng"

libgcc-ng                7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libstdcxx-ng             7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
```

Here I provide the `conda info`

```
     active environment : qiime_1_9_0
    active env location : /storage-daredevil/CONDA_ENVS/qiime_1_9_0
            shell level : 1
       user config file : $HOME/.condarc
 populated config files : $HOME/.condarc
                          /storage-daredevil/CONDA_ENVS/qiime_1_9_0/.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=3.10.0=0
                          __glibc=2.17=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /opt/miniconda  (read only)
      conda av data dir : /opt/miniconda/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/free/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/free/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/biobakery/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/biobakery/noarch
          package cache : /opt/miniconda/pkgs
                          $HOME/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /storage-daredevil/CONDA_ENVS
                          $HOME/.conda/envs
                          /opt/miniconda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.7 Linux/3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 centos/7.9.2009 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 1060:20
             netrc file : $HOME/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

Can anyone help me? (I'm sorry the environment seems to be a mess, but someone else created it)
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Both those packages resolve fine for me. Please add output of `conda info`. Also, note that `conda list` takes a regex argument - no need to be using `grep`. E.g., `conda list 'lib(gcc|stdcxx)-ng'`. Finally, I’d again emphasize that you still don’t justify *why* you need to install in this environment - seems like a very unproductive use of your time - which is why my main answer is to create a new environment.

Comment: Please, see the edited question above, with the attached `conda info`. I understand that the straightforward way to install `fastspar` would be creating an _ad hoc_ environment. My idea was to keep it in the same environment where I would use it most, i.e. QIIME. Moreover, the `ResolvePackageNotFound` pops up for every operation I try on the `qiime_1_9_0` environment: thus, beside the operation that originally raised the question, I'm interested in finding a way to resolve this broken environment (if this exists) without re-creating the whole environment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I approach software management differently (lots of small, immutable environments that accomplish dedicated tasks) and maybe won't convert you to my perspective. I understand that you would like to mutate the existing environment, and this means resolving the channel issue. Not sure I can troubleshoot it any further, since everything is solving fine for me. Have you tried solving it with Mamba instead? It can have its own quirks, but sometimes can solve cases where Conda chokes.

Answer (score 0):

Without any justification given for installing in an environment running an EOL Python, I would recommend creating a new environment. The desired package does not even have a Python dependency.

Also, be sure to follow the Bioconda guidance on channels (`conda-forge > bioconda > defaults`).

```bash
## (optional, but recommended) use mamba
conda install -n base mamba

mamba create -n foo -c conda-forge -c bioconda fastspar
```

---

As for the actual error, sounds like you used the `free` channel *ad hoc*, but didn't actually add it to the channel configuration or set `restore_free_channel` configuration setting. I would only do this inside the *activated* environment with this dated software. Either

**Option 1: Add `free` as channel**

```
## activate the environment, say "foo"
conda activate foo

## add free channel at lowest priority 
## (the `--env` makes it only apply to this environment)
conda config --env --append channels free

## check the configuration
conda config --show channels
```

This should show the `free` channel at the bottom of a list. If `free` is the only channel, then be sure to also `--prepend` something like `defaults`.

**Option 2: Set configuration**

```bash
## activate the environment, say "foo"
conda activate foo

## add free channel at lowest priority
conda config --env --set restore_free_channel true
```

Be sure to always activate this environment before installing in it. Though, again, any environments running old software should be regarded as legacy, i.e., leave it alone, and only use it to run old code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding the `free` channel to my environment and install `fastspar`, ma with no success. I updated the original post accounting for this try

Comment: @MarcoSevergnini Also, note that you will have to use `channel_priority: flexible` in order for packages in `free` to be considered in a solve.

Comment: Thank you @merv. At least, I made a step forward. Using `channel_priority: flexible`, I was able to get rid of many of the `ResolvePackageNotFound`. However, it still complains about two packages: `libgcc-ng` and `libstdcxx-ng`. See the edited post for some more information